# Can we create two login pages with their separate routing in a single Angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Here, I am creating Angular 2 application with distributed database and micro-service architecture. In my application scenario,
the application condition is that we are having normal user functionality as well as admin functionality like modify, delete organization attributes etc.

Suppose,

a normal user is trying to log in, he will get redirected to application functionality with its routing.

But, if an admin user is trying to log into the application, he should have the choice of admin functionality or normal application functionality.

For achieving this, I am thinking of two approaches:

- Approach:  Create two separate Projects (one for application functionality and other for admin functionality), so that admins can have a URL for both and he can access any one of them at will
- Approach: Thinking to build Role based architecture using route guards in single application only, and activate admin functionality page whenever admin will be logged-in

But, confusion regarding security of application. Can my second approach gives security that hackers could not hack my admin rights through that page as it will be part of the same application? Which one will be the more suitable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 is the best approach but need some authentication and best practices to manage routes as well as conditions of all application

As it will decrease the time of development as well as integrity and you also manage the website easily but having a large complexity.

But as most industries are using such as Flipkart, Amazon they have different portals for sellers, admin, and users.

In admin panel they enable role based login such as account, manager, Sr. Mgr, customer support if it is such a complex architecture go for 1st option

Comment: I am having single page Admin functionality which includes modify, delete the organization Attributes and Also Uploading data. So still need to follow 1 approach?

Comment: Yes, I am also thinking so as this big giant working in this manner and keeps both projects isolated from each other. which is good for even your team

Comment: If you satisfy and clear with architecture so upvote and accept my answer and if left with anything kindly post

Comment: Can we merge two applications into single one? So there will be only one URL for application?

Comment: Yes, you can but I had to install python when I used first time in Linux Mint

Comment: How can I merge two applications into one?

Comment: Create Modules for Admin and User and for every feature create modules and using services maintain your architecture

Comment: Did you have any sample application for this. If yes, please send me link. Thanking you.

Comment: santosh.matlab.singh@gmail.com ping me on hangouts

Answer (score 1):

I personally would go with `Seacond` approach.

There very beauty of using frameworks for making app is that you dont need to worry about various aspect (including security) that you have to manually manage while making normal website using various libraries.

`User` not able to enter `admin panel` is such small aspect compared to all aspects covered by Angular. https://angular.io/guide/security

They have given complete guideline and methods like `authGaurd`, `canResolve` which you can use and focus on development without worrying. The only thing to worry about is your knowledge of using angular. ;)